# Determine robot's position in a nearby room

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, precise-positioning

**Scenario**

I have 2 roaming robots, each in different rooms of a house, and both robots are connected to the house wifi. Each robot only has access to the equipment on itself.

**Question**

How can the robots be aware of each other's exact position using only their own equipment and the house wifi?

**EDIT: Additional Info**

Right now the robots only have:

- RGBDSLAM via Kinect
- No initial knowledge of the house or their location (no docks, no mappings/markings, nada)
- Can communicate via wifi and that part is open ended

I'm hoping to be able to stitch the scanned rooms together before the robots even meet. Compass + altimeter + gps will get me close but the goal is to be within an inch of accuracy which makes this tough. There IS freedom to add whatever parts to the robots themselves / laptop but the home needs to stay dynamic (robots will be in a different home every time).

Comment: What does access mean here? Does it only mean that one robot can't access the eqipment on the other robot? However, if each robot has the ability to measure its own pose, can't it transfer this data through wifi to the other robot?

Comment: What sensors / equipment are on your robots?  (Lidar, IMU, odometry, stereo/mono camera, etc.)  Are they running SLAM?  Do the robots know their own position?  Do they each have a map of the entire house?  Are there docks or other known landmarks or locations?  Can the robots talk to each other?  Do the robots know what code or behavior logic is running on the other robot?  More detail in your question will improve the answers you get.

Comment: @Ben I added more detail to help give a better picture of the situation.

Comment: @bluebird Yes, all of a robots data is transferable via wifi. Camera footage, mappings, localization, etc.

Comment: @Jackson since both robots have their own SLAMs, you may consider utilizing one global frame for both SLAMs.

Comment: @CroCo That's part of the idea I'm going for. I just don't know how to make the relative localization of the bots converge to a global localization with limited information about the environment. I've got to make sure distance & orientation matches, among others.

Comment: You said both robots can communicate with each other. Basically each SLAM can provide you with an estimate of the robot's location relative to one global frame, therefore, two robots are navigating one global frame. I don't see any problem in here.

Comment: @CroCo I see what you're saying. In my case the robots come into the situation completely blind and have to piece everything together. Think of two people blindfolded and put into different rooms of a house in a location. I give them walkie-talkies and remove the blindfolds. What other tools would they need to find out the orientation & location of the other?

Comment: @Jackson, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can utitilize one global frame for both robots since each robot has its own SLAM. SLAM provides an estimate for a robot's pose (i.e. location and direction). If you unify the global frame for both SLAMs, then you can determine the poses of the two robots. I've drawn a picture to illustrate my approach.

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, two robots are placed in one global frame. Once they start running, there is one landmark in this picture. Each SLAM will utilize this landmark to estimate the robot's pose, therefore, since the robots can communicate with each other, each robot can have an estimate for the other robot's pose.

Comment: This technically solves my question but in situations where time is of the essence do you have any tips for solving this problem as fast as technologically possible?

Comment: SLAM is capable of running in online process. Think about Driverless cars where SLAM is utilized to provide the robot's pose instantly. This depends on the way SLAM is implemented which irrelevant to your question however, it is really interesting question. Feel free to ask it in an independent post.